# PAM failing to authenticate all users from one domain in dovecot

Tags: postfix, smtp, dovecot

I have installed a mail server using Dovecot + Postfix, and it always worked correctly.

Recently I installed a new domain `example.com` and a user `info@example.com` for that domain in the mailserver database in SQL. While Dovecot (POP) retrieves emails correctly for that user, postfix (SMTP) fails to send, and it returns the error "Service unavailable - try again later.". All other domains work correctly.

Looking at `systemctl status dovecot` I see that pam is failing to authenticate the email address:

`pam_unix(dovecot:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=5000 euid=5000 tty=dovecot ruser=info@example.com>`

Although I see that pam_unix is failing to authenticate other domains too, although they can receive and send correctly. When I send with a email user in another domain I see:

`dovecot[790]: lmtp(121689): Connect from local`

and this does not happen with the new domain. What should I do to further inverstigate?